# Creating dynamic group header in crystal report

Tags: c#-4.0, crystal-reports

I have a sort field in my cs code and when a user selects any sort field value then on the basis of that, group header must be created, I have no clue of writing a group formula, can I get some basic help in this regard as how to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to set dynamic header, there is no need for the header formula sometimes. Its like pass a value from the data table to one of the fields in the data set and that field can be placed at the Header position with proper formatting so that when report is run we can see the Report Header.